# Add myself as owner again of a team in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I accidently changed my role in a team I created in Microsoft Teams from "Owner" to "Member" for myself, meaning I apparently no longer control the group and can see some administrative settings. I got no warning. Is it possible to get back my administrative capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

As you are no longer owner of the team, you cannot make change to your role from Teams itself.
If you have access to [Teams admin centre](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/), then go to Teams -> Manage Teams.
Select the team you want to make changes to; all members will be listed. Change your role from Member to Owner.